# VueJS - process.env.NODE_ENV equals "development" even though "--mode production" is set

Tags: vue.js, webpack, production-environment, production, webpack-production

I'm trying to get my VueJS app ready for production.
Case across the issue in the title.
How do I get my app ready from production and distinguish between
dev/prod environments, without relying on process.env.NODE_ENV (since 
it's not working as expected).

Thanks!

P.S.
Haven't edited webpack directly, 
only fiddled with vue.config.js.